# Multiple Controllers Zend Framework 2 - Entity Manager Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, frameworks, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2.2.2 and Doctrine2 Module 0.7.0.

My goal is to have my functions related to a task in a standalone php-class. My current workflow is between two different programms: get data -> modify and store data -> send data.

This workflow needs functions from 3 ZF2 modules:
1. source software module
2. internal storage mechanism module
3. destination software module

The first task is successfull but when I move my data to the second module like this (shrinked to the main code):

```
use MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngineController;

/** @var  \MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngineController */
private $_newsletterEngine;

$this->_newsletterEngine = new NewsletterEngineController();
[...]
$this->_newsletterEngine->addNewNewsletterRecipient($emailAddresses,1);
```

The second Controller has problems getting the service locator:

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\trunk\module\MTNewsletterEngine\src\MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngineController.php on line 51

Line 51:

```
$em_mtnewsletterengine = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_mtnewsletterengine');
```

NewsletterEngineController is the Main Controller from Module MTNewsletterEngine.

I am confused as I don't know how to get this solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create a new instance of `NewsletterEngineController` by using the `new` keyword. The ServiceLocator will not be injected to the created object this way. Use  *Zend\ServiceManager* to retrieve an instance of `Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager` (alias: *"ControllerLoader"* (ci)) and use the `get` method, to load the target controller. `Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager` extends the ServiceManager itself (because it is a plugin manager).

Check your module.config.php. The controller should be listed as an invokable controller.

### Example:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngine' => 'MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngineController'
    ),
),
```

```
$this->_newsletterEngine = $this->getServiceLocator()
        ->get('ControllerLoader')
        ->get('MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngine');
```

For more information read the manual and try to understand the way the ServiceManager / ServiceLocator (which is part of *Zend\Di*) works.

Maybe you should also think about the structure of your application. I am not sure what you are trying to do there but it seems like you are mixing up different application layers.

### Docs

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-di
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-servicemanager

Comment: I tried this but I get Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for MTNewsletterEngine\Controller\NewsletterEngine but the Controller is in my invokables like your code.

Comment: You are right. The ServiceManager does not load the controllers. The ServiceManager loads a PluginManager called `Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager` which is responsible for loading controllers and injecting dependencies. I have edited my answer and tested the code on ZF 2.2

Comment: Thanks for your edit, this works awesome! No more passing of the ServiceManager via params!